# alineamiento de imagenes

Tags: css, imagen, div, margin

tengo una pregunta, cuando quiero poner una imagen a la izquierda, pero por más que lo intento, no lo consigo, alguien me puede ayudar? pongo el html y css:

```
<div class="flecha">
            <br>
            <section id="flecha">
                <div><img class="imagendecentro" src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/135678/isolated/preview/6249ee44af81d1f8a400be3246d0bb39-icono-de-circulo-de-almacenamiento-en-la-nube.png" alt="logo del almacenamiento"></div>
                <div class="unificacion"><h3>Almacenamiento</h3>
                <p>Almacenamiento de 64GB, perfecto para cualquier tipo de archivo de gran tamaño. Se puede usar para videos y fotos
                    con un peso considerable, puede incluso usarse para hacer una instalación limpia de Windows 10 y ser ejecutada 
                    desde el mismo.
                </p></div>
            </section>
        </div>
```

Y el css:

```
#flecha {
display: flex;
```

}

```
.unificacion {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
height: 125px;
width: 80vw;
padding: 5px;
```

}

```
div p {
margin: 0px;
text-align: left;
font-size: 16px;
```

}

```
div h3 {
margin-bottom: 0px;
font-size: 24px;
```

}

quiero que el icono se quede en el centro, pero no lo consigo, esta es la imagen.
(PD: me estoy iniciando en el html, soy muy nuevo, 3 días, no me peguen si es fácil :()

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parcialmente lo estás haciendo bien. Debes agregarle a `#flecha`  `.flecha` Tres propiedades importantes: el ancho, el flex y el align. Ya que `#Flecha` es el elemento padre, de igual forma lo haces con la clase `.flecha`

Lo importante aqui para lo que requieres es colocarle la propiedad `flex-wrap: wrap`   al `section.flecha` para indicarle que los dos `divs` van a permanecer cada uno en una linea.

```css
    #flecha, .flecha{
        width:100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .flecha {
        flex-wrap: wrap; /* HE AQUI LA MAGIA */
    }

    .unificacion {
        height: 125px;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    div p {
        margin: 0px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    div h3 {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        font-size: 24px;
    }
    
    img{
        width:200px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="flecha">
    <section class="flecha">
        <div>
            <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/135678/isolated/preview/6249ee44af81d1f8a400be3246d0bb39-icono-de-circulo-de-almacenamiento-en-la-nube.png" alt="logo del almacenamiento">
        </div>
        <div class="unificacion">
            <h3>Almacenamiento</h3>
            <p>Almacenamiento de 64GB, perfecto para cualquier tipo de archivo de gran tamaño. Se puede usar para videos y fotos
            con un peso considerable, puede incluso usarse para hacer una instalación limpia de Windows 10 y ser ejecutada 
            desde el mismo.
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```